# What is the expected number of matching pairs in a stable matching problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the expected number of matching pairs in a stable matching problem involving n companies and n applicants where each company and applicant has their own independently generated preference list?

Comment: Do you mean the expected number of stable pair-lists?

Comment: Yes, the expected value of stable pairs